# Universal app with landscape only not work good in iPad - Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I build a app that not allow portrait orientation.

[image]

when I run the app in iPhone its open in landscape , and on iPad its open in portrait.

I need that the all devices open in landscape.

what I do wrong ?

Comment: What version of XCode are you using? In mine (7.2), before Main Interface, I have a UISegmentedControl to chose either iPhone or iPad and set the Device Orientation for each one differently.

Comment: 7.3.1 its my  Xcode version